# Print table for loop error

Tags: java, jsp, for-loop, printing, html-table

Hi every body I have this jsp page that should print all available cards after calling the method showAvailableCards(). This happens in a for cycle that loops through the ArrayList and out.print does the rest. The problem is that my for cycle prints a table for each record. How solve this? Below my code:

```
                    List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
                    Association asso = new Association();
                    cards = asso.showAvailableCards();
                    out.print("<br>");
                    out.print("<h2>Available cards:</h2>");

                    for (int i = 0; i < cards.size(); i++) {
                        Card card = new Card();
                        card = cards.get(i);


                    out.print("<Table width=110% align=center border='1'>");
                    out.print("<td><input type=hidden name=\"idcard\" ></td>");
                    int idcard = card.getId();
                    out.print("<tr><th>card Id</th>\n<th>Card number</th>\n <th>Attivation code</th>\n <th>Pin</th>\n <th>Amount</th>\n <th>Expiry date</th>\n <th>Select</th>\n</tr>");
                    out.print("<td align=center>" + card.getId()+ "</td>");
                    out.print("<td align=center>" + card.getCardNumber()+ "</td>");
                    out.print("<td align=center>" + card.getAttCode()+ "</td>");
                    out.print("<td align=center>" + card.getPin() + "</td>");
                    out.print("<td align=center>&#8364; "+ card.getAmount() + "</td>");
                    out.print("<td align=center>" + card.getExpiryMonth()+ "/" + card.getExpiryYear() + "</td>");
                    out.print("<td align= center><input type=\"button\" value=\"Select\" onclick=\"exeForm(1,'CardExe.jsp',"+card.getId()+")\">");

                    out.print("</table>");
                    }
```

Comment: I suppose you could start by not printing a new `<table>` inside your for loop, which will print a new table for every iteration of the loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put these line:

```
out.print("<Table width=110% align=center border='1'>");
```

before the loop. 
and this line after the loop:

```
out.print("</table>");
```

furthermore: add the `tr` tag inside the loop.

so you get:

```
       out.print("<Table width=110% align=center border='1'>");
 for (int i = 0; i < cards.size(); i++) {
                    Card card = new Card();
                    card = cards.get(i);


               out.print("<tr>");
                out.print("<td><input type=hidden name=\"idcard\" ></td>");
                int idcard = card.getId();
                out.print("<tr><th>card Id</th>\n<th>Card number</th>\n <th>Attivation code</th>\n <th>Pin</th>\n <th>Amount</th>\n <th>Expiry date</th>\n <th>Select</th>\n</tr>");
                out.print("<td align=center>" + card.getId()+ "</td>");
                out.print("<td align=center>" + card.getCardNumber()+ "</td>");
                out.print("<td align=center>" + card.getAttCode()+ "</td>");
                out.print("<td align=center>" + card.getPin() + "</td>");
                out.print("<td align=center>&#8364; "+ card.getAmount() + "</td>");
                out.print("<td align=center>" + card.getExpiryMonth()+ "/" + card.getExpiryYear() + "</td>");
                out.print("<td align= center><input type=\"button\" value=\"Select\" onclick=\"exeForm(1,'CardExe.jsp',"+card.getId()+")\">");
               out.print("</tr>");

                }
                out.print("</table>");
```

Answer (score 1):

I also tried this:

```
                List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
                Association asso = new Association();
                cards = asso.showAvailableCards();
                out.print("<br>");
                out.print("<h2>Available cards:</h2>");
                out.print("<Table width=100% align=center border='1'>");
                out.print("<input type=hidden name=\"idcard\">");
                out.print("<tr><th>card Id</th><th>Card number</th><th>Attivation code</th> <th>Pin</th><th>Amount</th><th>Expiry date</th> <th>Select</th></tr>");

                for (int i = 0; i < cards.size(); i++) {
                    Card card = new Card();
                    card = cards.get(i);

                    out.print("<tr>");
                    int idcard = card.getId();
                    out.print("<td align=center>" + card.getId() + "</td>");
                    out.print("<td align=center>" + card.getCardNumber + "</td>");
                    out.print("<td align=center>" + getAttCode() + "</td>");
                    out.print("<td align=center>" + card.getPin() + "</td>");
                    out.print("<td align=center>&#8364; " + card.getAmount()
                            + "</td>");
                    out.print("<td align=center>" + card.getExpiryMonth() + "/"
                            + card.getExpiryYear() + "</td>");
                    out.print("<td align= center><input type=\"button\" value=\"Select\" onclick=\"exeForm(1,'CardExe.jsp',"
                            + card.getId() + ")\">");
                    out.print("</tr>");

                }
                out.print("</table>");
```

Slightly better imho. Yet I wouldn't have done that without your help. Thank you.